# Wicket 6: TextField cursor position moves when component updated

Tags: javascript, java, wicket, textfield, wicket-6

I have a component that wraps a Wicket TextField that, upon update, I validate it's contents via some other outer class responsible for model validation.

If the contents is invalid I update the wrapper component to display an error.

This has the effect of updating the wrapped TextField.

The problem is that when this update occurs the cursor within the text field jumps to position 0.

By 'update' I mean that I am adding the TextField component (or parent container component/Panel) to an AjaxRequestTarget for update.

Is there any [nice] way to prevent this cursor jump from happening and have it just left where it is?

Comment: can you post code also ?

Comment: What JavaScript event initiates the validation?

Comment: To clarify, if the cursor in the text field is say, midway between the text, and then for whatever reason I add that TextField component to an AjaxRequestTarget for update, the cursor then jumps to position 0 in the text. @svenmeier - Javascript does not initiate the validation - a capture of the FormComponentUpdate Behaviour does (onUpdate)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I didn't search around hard enough - I can point to a solution found here:

http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/TextField-cursor-reset-mid-editing-td4668582.html

Specifically, the post further down by:

ChambreNoire Dec 04, 2014; 4:19pm Re: FIXED: TextField cursor reset mid-editing

This worked for me nicely, but just to note that you should not force an update of the component if the text contents of the TextField model hasn't changed, otherwise when you select text via keyboard method (shift+arrow keys, etc) then the selection will fail and the cursor will revert to the position held before the selection.

Actually, since forum posts have a tendency to disappear, here is the text of the post below:

```
OK so this is what I have. Disclaimer: I'm no javascript/jQuery expert so this is mostly cobbled together from things I have found online and tested in my particular situation. Any optimisations are more than welcome! 

So first the script 

(function($) { 
$.fn.getCaretPosition = function() { 
    var input = this.get(0); 
    if (!input) return; // No (input) element found 
    if ('selectionStart' in input) { 
        // Standard-compliant browsers 
        return input.selectionStart; 
    } else if (document.selection) { 
        // IE 
        input.focus(); 
        var sel = document.selection.createRange(); 
        var selLen = document.selection.createRange().text.length; 
        sel.moveStart('character', -input.value.length); 
        return sel.text.length - selLen; 
    } 
}; 
$.fn.setCaretPosition = function(position) { 
    var input = this.get(0); 
    if (!input) return false; // No (input) element found 

    input.value = input.value; 
    // ^ this is used to not only get "focus", but 
    // to make sure we don't have it everything -selected- 
    // (it causes an issue in chrome, and having it doesn't hurt any other browser) 

    if (input.createTextRange) { 
        var range = input.createTextRange(); 
        range.move('character', position); 
        range.select(); 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        // (input.selectionStart === 0 added for Firefox bug) 
        if (input.selectionStart || input.selectionStart === 0) { 
            input.focus(); 
            input.setSelectionRange(position, position); 
            return true; 
        } else  { // fail city, fortunately this never happens (as far as I've tested) :) 
            input.focus(); 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
} 
})(jQuery); 

Then I add the following behavior to my TextField : 

add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onkeyup") { 

@Override 
protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) { 

    String id = getComponent().getMarkupId(); 

    String caret = id + "_caretPosition"; 
    String selector = "$('#" + id + "')"; 

    target.prependJavaScript("var $s = " + selector + ";if($s[0]===document.activeElement){" + 
            "jQuery.data(document,'" + caret + "'," + selector + ".getCaretPosition());}"); 

    onFieldUpdate(getFormComponent(), target); 

    target.appendJavaScript("var $p = jQuery.data(document,'" + caret + "');" + 
            "if($p!=undefined){" + selector + ".setCaretPosition($p);" + 
            "jQuery.removeData(document,'" + caret + "');}"); 
} 

@Override 
protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) { 
    super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes); 

    String id = getFormComponent().getMarkupId() + "_onkeyup"; 

    attributes.setThrottlingSettings(new ThrottlingSettings(id, seconds(1), true)); 
} 
}); 

So this gets round the 'zapping focus back to the original field after hitting tab' issue I experienced as the behavior will be called a bit after I hit tab due to the throttle settings but that won't affect whether the field is focused or not (it won't regain focus). So I can check this and bypass the whole thing if the field isn't focused simply by not storing the caret position and consequently not re-setting it. 

You'll notice I'm storing the caretPosition in 'document' using jQuery.data(). There's probably a more 'js/jquery best practices' way to do this. I should also be clearing the position once I set it (thinking out loud) so I'll add that above. 

CN
```